# convert text to number in case of an error in Bash

Tags: linux, bash, command-line-interface

I am running this command which usually returns a number. In cases of error, this parses into text which later on can cause error. How can I prevent this ?

```
folder_get_time=$((time  /opt/alluxio/bin/alluxio fs copyToLocal "$SRC" "$COPY_TO_LOCAL" )2>&1 >/dev/null )
```

Comment: You can either use `||` to execute a routine on command failure or use `2> /dev/null` to redirect only stderr

Comment: Does the `alluxio` command set its exit code to non-zero when it fails?

Comment: IN some cases it does, in most cases it just omits text

Comment: so parse the text?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you can't reliably trap the error

```
if folder_get_time=$((time /opt/alluxio/bin/alluxio fs copyToLocal "$SRC" "$COPY_TO_LOCAL" )2>&1 >/dev/null )
then
    echo "success" >&2
else
    rc=$?
    echo "fail" >&2
    exit $rc
fi
```

maybe check for a non-numeric output.

```
case $folder_get_time in
  '' | *[!0-9]*) echo "fail" >&2; exit 127 ;;
esac
```

Comment: Thanks! Assuming I have 5-6 of them running , can I use this as a function or a part of jq?

Comment: I don't see how this has anything with JSON to do. Probably post a separate question with more details. Putting code in a function is obviously trivial; if your code is `code; more code` then `func () { code; more code; }` names a function named `func` which contains it.